# Materialize CSS on chip delete

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, materialize

I have been trying to get the tag of a deleted [chip](https://materializecss.com/chips.html) from the `div` in the Materialize *chips* class, but nothing is working.

Here is what I have already tried.

```
$('.chips').on('chip.delete', function(e, chip){
    console.log(chip);
    console.log(e);
    console.log(chip.tag);
});
```

None of the above is working.

With just only `console.log(chip)`, I get undefined error in JavaScript console, but the function is firing when I delete the chip. I am just not able to get the value of tag of deleted chip. I want to store the tag in a variable.

I am creating chips dynamically on Materialize date select:

```
$('#pm_date').change(function () {
    var chipvalue = $(this).val();

    if (chipvalue !== "") {

        // checking if tag already exits
        if ($("#date_chip_select:contains(" + chipvalue + ")").length > 0) {
            alert('Date already selected');
        } else {
            var appendstring = "<div class='chip' id='date_chip_child_" + chip_id + "'>" + chipvalue + "<i class='material-icons close'>close</i></div>";
        }
    }
});
```

Here is the fiddle: *https://jsfiddle.net/hq22mne4/1/*

Comment: can you show us more code...... as it is working fine for me https://jsfiddle.net/hq22mne4/

Comment: `chip.delete` is not valid jQuery event. That is a bad approach. Better you can connect your chip deleting function with the code you want to run when a chip is deleted.

Comment: i am dynamically adding chips on materialize date select

Comment: can you fiddle it?

Comment: i have updated the fiddle

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`chips.js`, which is part of `materialize`, doesn't seem to expose any methods for adding or removing chips programmatically. It seems to exclusively listen for an `enter keydown` event and then internally add the chip.

So, I stitched together a workaround that does just that. I set potential chip's value within your `onchange` event:

```
$("#datechips").find('input').val($(this).val());
```

And create the chip when [date picker is closed](http://amsul.ca/pickadate.js/api/#method-on-callback-options):

```
$('.datepicker').pickadate({
    selectMonths: true,
    selectYears: 15,
    onClose: function() {
        // add chip via filling the input and simulating enter
        $("#datechips").find('input').trigger({ type : 'keydown', which : 13 });
},
});
```

It may not be ideal, but you should be able to tailor this going forward.

https://jsfiddle.net/j3ej8240/

Answer (score 4):

I've also had a lot of trouble working this out. This is how I capture the add and delete chip events without using jQuery:

```js
function chipDeleted(e, data) {
    console.log("Chip was deleted with text: " + data.childNodes[0].textContent);
}

function chipAdded(e, data) {
    console.log("Chip was added with text: " + data.childNodes[0].textContent);
}


//
document.addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded", function (e) {
    console.log("DOM fully loaded and parsed");
    var firstTag = "Initial Tag";
    var elems = document.querySelectorAll('.chips');
    var instances = M.Chips.init(elems, {
        data:[{
              tag: firstTag
          }],
        autocompleteOptions: {

            limit: Infinity,
            minLength: 1
        },
        placeholder: "No search...",
        onChipDelete: function (e, data) { chipDeleted(e, data) },
        onChipAdd: function (e, data) { chipAdded(e, data) }
    });
});
```

And my HTML part is like this:

```html
<body>
    <div class="chips search-history"></div>

    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/materialize/1.0.0-beta/js/materialize.min.js"></script>

</body>
```